# c# sql подключение к бд

Tags: c#, sql

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД (точнее, проверить, работает ли соединение вообще с этой бд). Выбрасывает вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который я использую для подключения:

```
public const string connectString = "datasource = server7.hosting.reg.ru;port=3306;username=тут указан мой логин;password=тут указан мой пароль";
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
if (await CheckDB())
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Pizdes ne ok");
}
}

public static async Task<bool> CheckDB()
{
    using MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
    try
    {
        await myConnection.OpenAsync();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

БД пытаюсь поставить на 2domains (бесплатная версия). Мне она нужна для диплома и покупать хостинг как-то не очень хочется, поэтому пытался найти бесплатный хостинг, но как-то не очень работает....

Comment: Вам `access denied for user` вроде как намекает на проблему.

Comment: Вероятная причина: нет разрешения на внешнее подключение к серверу БД. Поставьте на свой комп. MySQL Workbench и попробуйте подключить из этого приложения со своим адресом, именем и паролем. Наверняка не получится, хостеру не нужны проблемы с безопасностью, потому по-умолчанию удаленный доступ к серверу БД запрещен.

Answer (score 0):

1. Возможно бд быкует (можно сначала попробовать на локалке)
2. Поробуй добавить: `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`
3. Попробуй поменять `connectString` на:
   `public const string connectString = @"server=server7.hosting.reg.ru;port=3306;userid=тут указан мой логин;password=тут указан мой пароль";`

Comment: Догадки и "попробуй" лучше писать в комментариях. А 2 пункт вообще для древних дотнетов типа 4.5.2 и старше. Не тянет на ответ. Как насчет того, что данному юзеру разрешено подключение только с локалхоста? Типа настройки по умолчанию, не? По какой-то причине этого в списке ваших догадок нет.